# Parse the output from str(datetime Object) with strptime

Tags: python, datetime

Does Python str(datetime Object) return a string that cannot be readily parsed with strptime? Or do I miss something:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

tz = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
now = tz.localize(datetime.now())
print(str(now))
```

The above will return a time formatted like this `2020-02-11 12:38:35.110566-08:00`. There is a colon in the offset part of the time. But looking at the string formats here https://strftime.org/ there is no format to read that in because `2020-02-11 12:38:35.110566-0800` would be required.

I am aware that str() is not the correct way to convert datetime to str (even though that would be convenient). However, I am dealing with an upstream API that provides the time format that way. Is there a way to convert that time without additional string manipulation. Like:

```
tm = datetime.strptime('2020-02-11 12:38:35.110566-08:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')
```

Which throws a ValueError. Python version is 3.6.7. Would you consider that a bug in pytz?

Comment: I copied this line: `tm = datetime.strptime('2020-02-11 12:38:35.110566-08:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z') ` to a Python prompt. It does not throw a value error for me. It executes, and Python reports the value of `tm` as `datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 11, 12, 38, 35, 110566, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=57600)))`. This was Python 3.7 (I don't have 3.6 anymore) but I'm not aware of any recent change to `datetime` that would make a difference.

Comment: Indeed it does work in 3.7 but not in 3.6.7. I guess someone else found that before me ;)

Comment: I took the trouble to check in 3.6 and I got the same problem with the colon: `%z` matches -0800 but not -08:00. This is issue 24954 (https://bugs.python.org/issue24954) and it was indeed fixed in 3.7.